# Why did our kitchen faucet stop working?

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens, faucet

No water comes out of my kitchen faucet when I turn it on. Every other water outlet in the house is working fine, and the kitchen faucet was working fine until the last time we used it (two days ago). There is no trickle, it just doesn't work. I turned to shut-off valves on and off completely but nothing happened.

It's a single handle faucet with a built in sprayer. I took off the handle and also looked under the sink to see if there is anything obviously wrong or broken but either there isn't or I don't understand enough to be able to tell.

I'm happy to take the faucet off to look deeper, but the problem is I don't know what to look for. I would love any advice about how to proceed before I call a plumber.

Comment: Does the tap feel easier/harder/different to move and turn on than normal?

Comment: No, it feels the same as usual I would say.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other valve upstream of your sink that is closed? It's very odd for the faucet to suddenly completely stop flowing or at least leaking unless it has been worked on recently.

Comment: The last time that happened, we had the nipples between the copper elbow and the under-sink shutoff valve rust completely shut. The 1/2" iron nipple was a solid block of rust inside. We replaced every nipple in the sink supply lines with 1/2" copper NPT and haven't had an issue since.

Comment: Shimon: I have checked every other water supply in the house (and I'm sure of it because I have a very small house) and they all work fine. About a month ago I turned off the main supply to the house, emptied all of the water lines with the intent of hopefully fixing a water hammer issue in the laundry room (it worked), but no other work has been done recently.\\ Fiasco: Did the rust have a gradual effect or did it happen suddenly?

Comment: Sounds like a faulty cartridge to me, but I would start by checking the aerator. Next I'd loosen the connection at the shut off valve slightly to verify water will drip out there. Next I'd loosen the hose to sink connection slightly to verify water is getting there. If water is getting there, I'd open up the faucet. Oh, you might try some quick on and off turns on the faucet too. Who knows. You might get lucky.

Comment: The rust narrowed the pipe over time (20 years), the final chunks breaking loose and shutting it off was sudden and happened after work elsewhere on the water system. As @getterdun notes, taking the pipes loose at the under-sink shutoff and checking for water flow there showed that the water blockage was between the faucet and the water system. OTOH if you have water there, then you know it's the faucet valve cartridge, dish-sprayer diverter valve or aerator socked full of gunk that flushed through from the other work.

Comment: I checked the water supply and water was flowing normally. I also checked the sprayer and aerator and found no issues. I'm going to assume then that the cartridge is broken and will get a new one to install.